# nginx is started but not found service on ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx

I try to restart the apache service on ubuntu 16.04 but i can not because the port '80' is listened to by nginx.
But when I try to stop nginx, the service is not found.

```
netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6069/nginx


    systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

service nginx stop
Failed to stop nginx.service: Unit nginx.service not loaded.
```

So how can I stop nginx in order to restart apache ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

nginx on your machine was started in other way then systemd standard nginx service.

```
alex@openresty:~$ ps aux | grep nginx
root      2668  0.0  0.0  41040   928 ?        Ss   12:33   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty -p /usr/local/openresty/nginx/
nobody    2669  0.0  0.0  41040  3316 ?        S    12:33   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

Will show you the full path of running nginx with command line arguments. Here is example from my PC (I use Openresty bundle so your paths may vary).

Now take a look at nginx master process command line parameters. If -p is present you should use exactly the same to stop nginx. For my case it should be:

```
/usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty -p /usr/local/openresty/nginx/ -s stop
```

If -p is missed you may just

```
/usr/local/openresty/bin/openresty -s stop
```

It would stop nginx, but it may be possible that on your PC nginx is configured to run as not standard service, for example hand written systemd unit.
So on every reboot you will have nginx running again.